# Passing variables in cmd files and execute in linux

Tags: linux, windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I have an issue where a .cmd file is unable to send data to another cmd file.
As per requirement my first cmd file is getting an IP address to send to another cmd file which will further telenet to a linux box.

From first cmd file: Main_telnet.cmd

```
echo %IPAddress% >> telnet.cmd
```

Now in second file as this will run on a linux server

```
echo "$IPAddress"
telnet $IPAddress
```

I have tried using `telnet $1`

I am not sure if my first cmd file is passing the IP address or if the second file is unable to read.

Comment: Please someone help ... %IP% >> test.cmd and unable to read in linux by $1 , %IP% %1% ...

Comment: To start with read her: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html As a general refernce this help: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I really got, what's your problem.
Your Main_telent.cmd writes the content of the variable %IPaddress% into a file (it appends it to that file, that means, it adds an additional line - is that really, what you want to do?)
You can verify it with 'type telnet.cmd'.

Your second file: does it run on windows, as your first sentence implies or on linux, as you stated later?

Nevertheless (Windows or Linux): it would have to read the variable from file

EDIT: ah wait! Do you want to pass %IPAddress% as a parameter to telnet.cmd?

First cmd-file

```
REM Main_telnet.cmd
rem get ipaddress
echo %IPAddress%
telnet.cmd %IPAddress%
```

second cmd-file

```
REM telnet.cmd
echo connecting to: %1
telnet %1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for repsonse Stephan!!! My requirement is to get ip address from 1 file and to telnet to that IP from Linux box. Now I am able to login to linux box and echo any command which ever is mentioned in remote.cmd .... but I am unable to get IP from main file `%EXECMD% %TELNET_DIRECTORY%\putty.exe -l root -m %remote% -pw xxxxxx IP addres`... In above remote is set remote=C:\tmp\remote.cmd... Hope you understand my point... so for I am looking a command for reading IP address from 1st file to the other which will be open in linux server....

Comment: What is the content of telnet.cmd ?

Comment: telnet $IP  ...I am doing echo %IP% >> %remote.cmd%... remote.cmd=telnet.cmd ...now I have changed the name

Comment: Yes correct I want to pass %IPAdress to telnet.cmd which will be opned after establishing session with linux file .... please tell me how to read in telnet.cmd

Comment: I have tried from the below ways but unable to get ip address value from 1st cmd file....echo %1%
echo $1 
echo IPAddr
echo %IPAddr%
echo $IPAddr
echo %1% 
echo %2% 
echo %3%

Comment: Your second cmd-file is still on windows -right? Then try echo %1 (just %1, not %1%)

Comment: Any suggestions how to read IP after `echo %IPAddress% | telnet.cmd `

Comment: Thanks Stephan...  The problem is when telnet.cmd file gets open in Linux its reading %1 as %1 only ...I have tried $1 , %1% ,%IP% ...None of them are working..This means linux is not able to understand input from windows...